# Arduino C++ for loop exiting early?

Tags: c++, indexing, arduino, indexoutofboundsexception

I've been staring at this for most of the afternoon and am stumped. The problem seems so simple that I'm sure it will be a real Doh! face palm moment when I crack it.

Some background:

I'm creating a little project to use an Arduino to read in Infrared signals from my remote controllers and send them to a Python program I'm writing.

I send the sample command to the Arduino as a JSON string and use the Arduinojson library to deserialise it. That works fine. My sampling method captures the signal and writes it to an int array.

Where I'm struggling is converting that array to a JSON string. I tried using the same library for serialising it but it used a lot of memory, so I'm  trying to write a loop to convert the ints to string form and construct a JSON string manually from them.

My signal capture method:

```
// Capture an IR signal
bool capture() {
  bool captured = false;
  if(myReceiver.getResults()) {
    int index = 0;
    for(bufIndex_t i = 1; i < recvGlobal.recvLength; i++){
      irBuffer[index++] = recvGlobal.recvBuffer[i];

      // Debug
      Serial.print(i);
      Serial.print(" - ");
      Serial.println(recvGlobal.recvBuffer[i]);
    }
    irBuffer[index] = 0;
    captured = true;
  }
  myReceiver.enableIRIn();
  return captured;
}
```

The debug output from that method shows I'm capturing 67 pulses:

```
1 - 4400
2 - 4600
3 - 550
4 - 600
5 - 550
6 - 550
7 - 550
8 - 1650
9 - 550
10 - 1700
11 - 550
12 - 600
13 - 550
14 - 1650
15 - 600
16 - 550
17 - 550
18 - 600
19 - 500
20 - 600
21 - 550
22 - 550
23 - 550
24 - 1700
25 - 550
26 - 1650
27 - 550
28 - 600
29 - 550
30 - 1700
31 - 550
32 - 600
33 - 500
34 - 600
35 - 550
36 - 550
37 - 550
38 - 1700
39 - 550
40 - 1650
41 - 550
42 - 1700
43 - 550
44 - 1700
45 - 550
46 - 600
47 - 500
48 - 600
49 - 550
50 - 600
51 - 500
52 - 1700
53 - 550
54 - 600
55 - 550
56 - 550
57 - 550
58 - 600
59 - 500
60 - 600
61 - 500
62 - 1700
63 - 600
64 - 1650
65 - 550
66 - 1700
67 - 550
```

My attempt at converting this to a JSON string:

```
#define MAX_IR 100

...


if (RETURN_IR_SIGNAL) {
    char out[MAX_IR];
    char tmp[10];
    strcpy(out, "{\"signal\":[");
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_IR; i++) {
      if (irBuffer[i] == 0) {
        break;
      }
      // Debug statements
      Serial.print("out = ");
      Serial.println(out);

      sprintf(tmp, "%d,", irBuffer[i]);
      strcat(out, tmp);
    }
    strcat(out, "]}");

    // Debug
    Serial.println("Finished");

    RETURN_IR_SIGNAL = false;
  }
```

The debug output from that code is this:

```
out = {"signal":[
out = {"signal":[4400,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,550,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,550,550,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,550,550,1650,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,550,550,1650,550,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,550,550,1650,550,1700,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,550,550,1650,550,1700,550,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,550,550,1650,550,1700,550,600,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,550,550,1650,550,1700,550,600,550,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,550,550,1650,550,1700,550,600,550,1650,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,550,550,1650,550,1700,550,600,550,1650,600,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,550,550,1650,550,1700,550,600,550,1650,600,550,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,550,550,1650,550,1700,550,600,550,1650,600,550,550,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,550,550,1650,550,1700,550,600,550,1650,600,550,550,600,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,550,550,1650,550,1700,550,600,550,1650,600,550,550,600,500,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,550,550,1650,550,1700,550,600,550,1650,600,550,550,600,500,600,
out = {"signal":[4400,4600,550,600,550,550,55�␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀
```

You can see that when it gets to the 21st number in the array, it truncates the string to just a handful of numbers. Also, the fact that I don't see the final "Finished" message suggests that I'm maybe throwing an exception and restarting, but I have no way of seeing if that's the case.

It's been over twenty years since I've written any C or C++ and so it's been an uphill battle but enjoyable. So I daresay that this is a classic rooky error, but it's eluding me.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: That last intact line has 96 characters stored in `out`, which has space for 100. The next number will write past the end of the buffer.

Comment: I guess `irBuffer` is array of `int`. So you are expecting that converting array of `int` of size `MAX_IR` into strings and result string would fit into array of `char` of size `MAX_IR`?

Comment: In general, I do not know which arduino board you use, but anyway those are microcontrollers, they RAM measured in tens or hundreds of bytes, so approaches from PC (creating strings couple kilobytes long) may not work there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
strcat(out, tmp);
```

would lead to an eventual stack buffer overflow since the size of `out` buffer is just 100 *characters* (not integers) but you are writing much more than that into that character buffer after one stage of the iterations (at the 20th iteration to be precise).

I compiled your code snippet with ASAN enabled ([`-fsanitize=address`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer#Stack-buffer-overflow)) and it was easy to figure out the error. I hope resolving that issue should iron out this anomaly in printing, provided serial logging on the board accommodates such long strings. You could probably use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) or use an intermediate [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) , coupled with [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)and then stringify and dump it onto the console.

Comment: Thanks, as always, the answer came to me while I was dozing in bed last night. Upping the size got around the problem. You've mentioned a few things I'm not familiar with, like the ASAN. I'll read up on that and also look at using std::strings. Cheers! And thanks to the other commenters who also spotted the error ...